# Retain double quotes on registry value

Tags: python-3.x, registry, double-quotes

I'm trying to add a value to the registry which contains spaces and for that reason i want to retain double quotes.

I've tried escaping double quotes with '\"' but this had no effect

```
path_with_spaces = "C:\Users\me\i have space\app.exe"
argument_with_spaces = "Quick brown fox"

data = '"{}" -n "{}"'.format(path_with_spaces, argument_with_spaces)
command = 'REG ADD HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run /f /v test /d "{}"'.format(data)
subprocess.call(command)
```

if i print "command" i get:

*REG ADD HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run /f /v test /d ""C:\Users\me\i have space\app.exe" -n "Quick brown fox""*

but there are no double quotes to be seen while inspecting the result with regedit. Even if i do this:

```
data = '\"{}\" -n \"{}\"'.format(path_with_spaces, argument_with_spaces)
```

There is no change. The output when inspecting with regedit is always like this:

*C:\Users\me\i have space\app.exe -n Quick brown fox*

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you inject the `data` variable in the `command` variable, it is already a string. So If you wand to keep the`\` in the `command`, you have to double them in the `data` declaration

I think you could try something like this:

```
data = '\\"{}\\" -n \\"{}\\"'.format(path_with_spaces, argument_with_spaces)
```